# Constexpr if-then-else in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I require `constexpr if` in some part of my templated codebase, but since it is not available in C++11, I decided to come up with my own version of a simpler constexpr if-then-else.

Below is my implementation of constexpr if-then-else. I am not entirely sure if it is correct, and was unable to find any relevant content anywhere which suitably explains it. It would be really helpful if someone could verify this, and/or possibly point out alternative implementations.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename F>
constexpr F static_ite(std::false_type, T &&, F &&f) { return f; }

template <typename T, typename F>
constexpr T static_ite(std::true_type, T &&t, F &&) { return t; }

template <bool cond, typename T, typename F>
constexpr auto static_ite(T &&t, F &&f)
    -> decltype(static_ite(std::integral_constant<bool, cond>{}, std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<F>(f)))
{
    return static_ite(std::integral_constant<bool, cond>{}, std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

I intend to use it as a generic template. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Removed the language-lawyer tag, since you don't seem to be looking for any quotes from the standard.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you want the function to return a reference to whatever you give it; if you instead want a copy, refer to Yakk's answer.

---

The return types of the first two overloads should be rvalue references, and you should `std::forward` when you `return` from them.

The long `decltype` could be shortened to `typename std::conditional<cond, T &&, F &&>::type`.

Everything else looks good to me.

Comment: I agree with forward but not with rvalue reference return type; rvalue reference return types should only be used in very rare circumstances.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Well, it would give OP perfect forwarding. Why not?

Comment: because lifetime issues suck and cause UB easily by accident, and if someone needs perfect forwarding the value version can be used to do it with verbose extra code.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont can the rvalue reference version cause UB in this example, or are you talking about why returning rvalue references is generally avoided?

Comment: @SauravYadav Your code doesn't have any UB by itself. To get UB, you'd have to pass a temporary object to `static_ite`, then assign the result to a reference, which would give you a dangling reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T, typename F>
constexpr typename std::decay<F>::type static_ite(std::false_type, T &&, F &&f) { return std::forward<F>(f); }
```

and similar for other branch.  References can be passed through explicitly with std ref or pointers.

I find a more generic dispatch to be also useful:

```
template<std::size_t N, class...Ts>
nth_type<N,typename std::decay<Ts>::type...>
dispatch_nth(index_t<N>, Ts&&...ts);
```

(write obvious helpers).

This lets you work on more than 2 branches.

All of these become insanely more awesome with `auto` lambda paramerers; while that is [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) it was implemented in most early [c++1y](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1y) early implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this interface is that you are evaluating both sides of the conditional, so both sides need to be valid regardless of the value of the predicate. Because of this, it is more usual to pass in lambdas one of which will be invoked within the function. In addition, you may wish to pass in extra arguments so that when an expression is type-dependent you can ensure the type is only evaluated conditionally (though to use this effectively you may need C++14 generic lambdas).

Altogether, something like this:

```
template <bool cond, typename T, typename F, class... Args>
constexpr auto static_ite(T &&t, F &&f, Args&&... args)
    -> typename std::result_of<typename std::conditional<cond, T, F>::type&&(Args&&...)>::type
{
    return std::forward<typename std::conditional<cond, T, F>::type>(
        std::get<cond ? 0 : 1>(std::make_tuple(std::ref(t), std::ref(f)))(
            std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Note that this uses the `std::tuple` trick to bring everything within one function body; you can use your method of `std::true_type` / `std::false_type` overloading if you prefer.